# GGplot within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to do plot twice the same ggplot: once without function and once with function:

```
dat <- tibble(1:20, rnorm(20,0,1))
names(dat) <- c("var1", "var2")

# Version 1
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=var1, y=var2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, var1 <= 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=function(x){c(min(x)-1, max(x)+1)})

# Version 2
test <- function(dataset, aux1, aux2) {
  ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=aux1, y=aux2)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(data=subset(dataset, var1 <= 10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=function(x){c(min(x)-1, max(x)+1)})
}

attach(dat)
test(dat, var1, var2)
```

In the first case everythings works fine, in the second case I get the error: ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10)

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that works, where you specify as a parameter the subset.

```r
# Version 2
test <- function(dataset, mapping, dat_subset) {
  ggplot(data=dataset, mapping) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(data=subset(dataset, dat_subset <= 10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=function(x){c(min(x)-1, max(x)+1)})
}

test(dat, mapping = aes(x=var1, y=var2), dat_subset = dat$var1)
```

This documentation might really help you if you want something cleaner : https://ggplot2-book.org/programming

Answer (score 3):

Here is the recommended way:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = 1:20, var2 = rnorm(20,0,1))

test <- function(dataset, aux1, aux2) {
  ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x={{aux1}}, y={{aux2}})) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(data=subset(dataset, var1 <= 10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=function(x){c(min(x)-1, max(x)+1)})
}

test(dat, var1, var2)
```

Do not use `attach`, ever.

Comment: Thanks! Additional question: assume I have dat <- data.frame(var1 = 1:20, var2 = rnorm(20,0,1), var3= rnorm(20,1,3)). How can I change my code within the function to make sure, that I don't need to change manually var1 to var2 and var3 in the geom_point argument? (I would like to run a) test(dat, var1, var2) and the subset now should use var2 <= 1 and the b) test(dat, var1, var2) and the subset now should use var3 <= 1

Comment: Replace `var1` with `aux3` and make it a third parameter of the function?

Comment: What I would like to have is 
geom_point(data=subset(dataset, aux2 <= 10))
since it is the second argument of the function call. But this gives an error "var2" not found.

Comment: `geom_point(data=dplyr::filter(dat, {{aux2}} <= 10))`